# Unable to use lbrack; in Angular eventhough its a standard HTML

Tags: html, node.js, angular, angular-cli

I was using the `rbrack` and `lbrack` in my Angular code yesterday and I found out that Angular throws an error on this.

Code:

```
&lt;gen-pack-comp &lbrack;email&rbrack;="email""&gt;&lt;/gen-pack-comp&gt;
```

Error:

```
Error in src/app/genesis/gen.pack.component.html (3:53)
Unknown entity lbrack
```

I saw the Named Character references and the `rbrack` or `lbrack` is a HTML standard [U+0005B](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/named-character-references.html)

So, I wanted to know why its not supported or am I doing something wrong in the syntax?

Version:

```
Angular CLI: 11.1.0
Node: 15.7.0
OS: Windows x64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the hex or decimal (e.g. `&#x0005D;` and `&#93;` for rbrack) representation of the entity. Angular uses it's own HTML parser for templates, and the team decided to only include most used entity names to keep the parser size reasonably small.

You can find related git issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5546).